# Неверное вычисление итогового выражения

Tags: c++, vector

Добрый вечер. По заданию нужно рассчитать шаг арифметической прогрессии, делаю следующее:

```
long findMissing(std::vector<long> list)
{
    long step;
    step = (list.back()-list.front())/list.size();
    ...
}
```

При `list.back() = 123456` и `list.front() = -370368` итогом `step = 1073618368`, а должен быть -123456. При этом если изменить код на:

```
long findMissing(std::vector<long> list)
{
    long step;
    long int y=list.size();
    step = (list.back()-list.front())/y;
    ...
}
```

Всё приходит в норму и `step=-123456`. Можете объяснить почему так?[image: Пруфы, собственно]

IDE: *Qt Creator 5.10*,
компилятор: *MinGW 32-bit*. Задача с *CodeWars*, при компиляции там аналогичная проблема.

Comment: [Не воспроизводится](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FAER1x2SZRayJvrr).

Comment: @VTT Выглядит как магия, но проблема явно не локальная, хотя я не знаю какой компилятор на CW, но странно, что подобная проблема как тут так и там. У меня используется 11 стандарт, там 14. Мб хотя бы предположение почему так может происходить?

Comment: И ответ должен быть 123456, а никак не отрицательное число. Вы случаем `front` и `back` не перепутали? Если перепутали то тут у вас может иметь смешивание `signed` / `unsidnged` (потому что `list.size()` - `unsigned`). [Исправляется корректным приведением типа](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VPSR1hMBeJuMgU5u).

Comment: @VTT Исключено, скриншоты делал сразу после включения режима отладки

Comment: А чему равен `list.size()?`

Comment: @selya Очевидно 4.

Comment: @selya 4 элемента

Comment: @ProstoNekitos не глянул на скрин, было лень. Делить нужно так-то на количество промежутков, а не на количество элементов, т.е. на `size - 1`

Comment: @selya я не до конца расписал задание, поскольку не было нужды. В задании даётся арифметическая прогрессия в векторе с одним пропущенным числом, его, собственно и надо найти, а поскольку эл-та нет, то размер вектора = кол-во эл-ов полной прогрессии - 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В записи `(list.back()-list.front())/list.size();` результат `(list.back()-list.front())` будет неявно приводится к беззнаковому типу так как далее происходит деление на результат `list.size()`, который является беззнаковым. Во втором случае такая проблема не возникает, так как результат `list.size()` неявно приводится к знаковому типу при присваивании. Заметьте, что при использовании синтаксиса list initialization из С++11 такое неявное преобразование было бы ошибкой компиляции (`narrowing conversion`).

Соответственно проблема исправляется явным приведением типа:

```
step = (list.back()-list.front()) / static_cast<long>(list.size());
```

[Онлайн компилятор](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VPSR1hMBeJuMgU5u)